# How to bind one control to another?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, data-binding

I have a checkbox with a Checked property and a Listbox with an Enabled property.  I'd like to data bind the controls in such a manner that when the user checks the Checkbox, the listbox becomes enabled.  Conversely, when the user unchecks the checkbox, the listbox becomes disabled.

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, I should have done a bit of googling. The answer is actually pretty simple:

```
cbo.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", chk, "Checked");
```

Comment: Do you know how to input this using the Designer GUI?